# Python- Identifying values with a specific format + replace one of the elements in these values

Tags: python, regex, replace, bigdata

I would like to identify values in a column that have a specific format and then replace one of the elements, the 'x' with a '0'. For instance, the format is " >=3.1.x " or " >=9.5.x ". The desired output is " >=3.1.0 " or " >=9.5.0".  How do I replace the x with a 0?

Below is the code I started with:

```
format_x = re.compile(r"(?P<convert>(?:[>]?=?\d+\.\d+\.x))")

def convert_format_x(x):
    match = format_x.search(x["column_4"])    
    convert = match.group("convert")
    return
    
testing = testdata['column_4'].apply(convert_constraint, axis = 1)      
 
Output: 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.replace` for the task:

```py
df["column_4"] = df["column_4"].str.replace(
    r"(>=\d+\.\d+\.)x", r"\g<1>0", regex=True
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  column_4
0  >=3.1.0
1  >=9.5.0
2   =x.y.z
```

---

Dataframe used:

```
  column_4
0  >=3.1.x
1  >=9.5.x
2   =x.y.z
```

Comment: can you breakdown how the code in the replace brackets work? the code works, I just want to understand it better.  Another transformation I am trying to do replacing  '3.0 '  to read  '~3.0.0' or '4.1' with '~4.1.0'  but this requires adding an element on both ends of the value without replacing any element.  In other words, I want to add '~' and '.0' to the value.